# How to make a foreign key value NULL in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

```
class Table1
{
    int Id;
    int Var1;
    Table2? table2;
}

class Table2
{
    int Id;
    //Other fields
}
```

`Table1` refers to `Table2`. Since `Table2` field is nullable in class `Table1`, why can't I set it to null the following way?

```
var zeroVars = table1.where(i => i.Var1 == 0).ToList();

foreach (var t2 in zeroVars)
{
    t2.Var1= -1; // Works
    t2.table2 = null; // Does not change. No error
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you haven't eager loaded Table2 for the change tracking to know that you want to remove it. This should work as expected:

```
var zeroVars = table1
    .Include(i => i.table2)
    .Where(i => i.Var1 == 0)
    .ToList();

foreach(var t2 in zeroVars)
{
    t2.Var1= -1; 
    t2.table2 = null; 
}
```

If you don't load the reference then the value is effectively null to begin with, unless it is eager or lazy loaded before attempting to set it.